# What does _("some string here") mean in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project, and I saw a line in this file: https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap/blob/master/app/views/users/_admin_grant_permissions.html.erb

The line is:

```
<%= _('Manage organisation details') %></li>
```

Where does `_()` came from?

I open irb and paste the code but it gives:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `_' for main:Object)
```

However `rails c` gives:

```
> _('Manage organisation details')
 => "Manage organisation details"
> _.class
 => String
```

Where does the expression `_()` came from and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is localization function, defined in [gettext](https://github.com/ruby-gettext/gettext) gem.

As I see `gettext` is in that project's [Gemfile](https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap/blob/master/Gemfile#L62). That's why you can use it in Rails console and across the app.

https://github.com/ruby-gettext/gettext#_-basic-translation-method